# What is the maximum size of data that can be stored in an ID3D11Buffer?

Tags: c++, buffer, directx-11

As the question is stated above. What is the maximum size of data that can be stored in an ID3D11Buffer? e.g. store and pass all of the world matrices in a scene. Is there a difference if the buffer is constant?

Comment: In general, you would not populate a large buffer with each object's world matrix.  Instead, the typical approach is to create a single per-draw constant buffer, and [dynamically](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476259(v=vs.85).aspx#D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC) update it before each draw call.

Comment: Unless of course you're using instancing, which is good practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff819065(v=vs.85).aspx) would suggest the largest Buffer that you can create is either 25% the total size of VRAM or 2GB, whichever is smaller; with a guarantee of at least 128MB. I've never run into such a limit, so I expect it'll be large enough for your particular use case.